# Why is empty in this Abstract Syntax Tree?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, syntax-trees

I given the following code to write as AST:

```
 {
       a = 4;
       while (a<10)
         if (a<5)
           a = a+5;
         else
           a = a+3;
 }
```

Looking up the solution:

```
                       PROG
                         |
                        SEQ
         _______________/ \_______________
       SEQ                              WHILE
    ___/ \___                    ________/ \________
  EMPTY     EXPR                LT                _IF2_
             |                 / \         ______/  |  \______
           ASSIGN            VAR CST      LT      ASSIGN    ASSIGN
            / \               0  10      / \       / \       / \
          VAR CST                      VAR CST   VAR ADD   VAR ADD
           0   4                        0   5     0  / \    0  / \
                                                   VAR CST   VAR CST
                                                    0   5     0   3
```

Why is in the left side of the tree we have an EMPTY?

Why is the do we need SEQ why isn't it directly EXPR in the left side?

Comment: This depends on the grammar you're using. Can you describe it?

Comment: I guess it is because the left argument of `SEQ` is always a sequence of statements, and `EXPR` is not a sequence of statements, but a statement. `EMPTY` is the empty sequence of statements. See also how *lists* are defined inductively in functional programming languages like Lisp or Standard ML.